# Volume control independent from audio sources/listeners

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, a Unity project I am working on basically makes use of the volume of the music to effect some game mechanics.

I would like to add a volume level option for users but the only way I've found of doing this is by directly changing the output volume of the audio source(s) or directly changing what audiolisteners hear.

This is an issue because I am using AudioSource.GetSpectrumData, and if either source or listener volume are modified the spectrum data values drop alongside these values.

**So what I need is a way to control output volume levels of the game without changing the volume levels of any audio sources or listeners.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an Audio Mixer component you can set each of the audio listeners to be on a certain channel but there is a parenting system which means you can have a Master channel which effects all volume equally. [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioMixer.html) is the documentation for the component.

And here is a Unity tutorial on how to use it:

[Mixer](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/audiomixer-and-audiomixer-groups?playlist=17096)

[Parameters](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/audio/exposed-audiomixer-parameters?playlist=17096) (if desired)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an Audio Mixer from Unity? You would avoid touching the sources or the listeners.

As far as I know it's possible to control the parameters of an AudioMixer directly by exposing them and then set the values by using the SetFloat function.

Check this video from Unity : [exposed Audio mixer parameters](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/audio/exposed-audiomixer-parameters)